# get data-target and put into var with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, target

I guess it's a very basic question, but I really didn't get it to work.

Before opening a modal popup I'm reading out three data-targets with js.

```
var x = 2;
$('#confirm-delete').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
$(this).find('.btn-ok').attr('onclick', 'location.href=\'' + $(e.relatedTarget).data('href') + '\'');
$(this).find('input.timee').val($(e.relatedTarget).data('timess'));
$(this).find('input.prodtotext').val($(e.relatedTarget).data('prodid'));
$("#proddropchange").val(x.toString()).trigger('change');
});
```

This code works fine, but I want to remove the 4th line where I put the data-target "data-prodid" into the input "prodtotext". In return I want to read out the data-target "data-prodid" and put this value into "var x = 2"

With the value I'm setting the preselected value of a dropdown list which is different on every opened modal popup.

What I thought should work:

```
$('#confirm-delete').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
$(this).find('.btn-ok').attr('onclick', 'location.href=\'' + $(e.relatedTarget).data('href') + '\'');
$(this).find('input.timee').val($(e.relatedTarget).data('timess'));
$("#proddropchange").val(x.toString()).trigger('change');
var x = $(this).data("prodid");
});
```

Comment: It's a code smell that your `x` is defined immediately after the line that attempts to use it.  Also have you verified that `e.relatedTarget` and `this` are the same thing?

Comment: 1. true, and isn't in my actual code. 2. no.

Comment: Well e.relatedTarget and this was not the same which was one problem, see my solution.

Comment: Glad you figured it out, :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found my solution. Thank you for your advice.

```
$('#confirm-delete').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
$(this).find('.btn-ok').attr('onclick', 'location.href=\'' + $(e.relatedTarget).data('href') + '\'');
$(this).find('input.timee').val($(e.relatedTarget).data('timess'));
thisdata = $(e.relatedTarget).data('prodid');
$("#proddropchange").val(thisdata.toString()).trigger('change');
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to declare x outside the function

```
var x;
$('#confirm-delete').on('show.bs.modal', ....
```

advices:

```
1. Cache $ elements in var $this = $(this);
2. $(this).find('.btn-ok').on('click', function(){ location.href = ....})
```

Comment: This results in a error when I click the trigger to open the modal popup.